# TypeError: Invalid URL at new NodeError when typing the command npx hardhat run scripts/deployGoldenFoxNFT.js --network rinkeby

Tags: nft, hardhat, compiler, hardhat-deploy, npm

I run into this error when i try to run with Hardhat. Any idea of what it can be the solution? Thanks a lot in advance

[image]

Comment: Please check your RPC provider URL, there must be something wrong with your infura endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something to do with the Infura endpoint that you are using. Try to switch provider.

I use [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) (which is free) and it works great.

Follow these steps to sign up on Chainstack, deploy a node, and find your endpoint credentials:

1. [Sign up with Chainstack](https://console.chainstack.com/user/account/create).
2. [Deploy a node](https://docs.chainstack.com/platform/join-a-public-network).
3. [View node access and credentials](https://docs.chainstack.com/platform/view-node-access-and-credentials).

They also have a page in the docs with a lot of [JSON-RPC API call examples](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/node-api-reference), and the code actually works!